# Why glass slab don't show dispersion as prism does?

Tags: dispersion

Why glass slab don't show dispersion as prism does?

I have got two answers and I am confused

1. The dispersion that occur at first interface with some angles , that hot reversed at second interface and hence, combine to form white light again
2. Answer to Why does dispersion of light occur in a prism but not in a rectangular glass slab? by Yaman Sanghavi https://www.quora.com/Why-does-dispersion-of-light-occur-in-a-prism-but-not-in-a-rectangular-glass-slab/answer/Yaman-Sanghavi?ch=15&oid=68019156&share=ef2af85c&srid=hrHyD7&target_type=answer

In diagram(rough , sorry!) :-

1. [image]
2. [image]

Please tell which one is correct? And if neither than please answer it in detail.

Comment: The dispersed rays are parallel to each other and do not diverge, hence our eyes still perceive them to be white light (The distance between parallel rays of different wavelengths is very small and it remains small)

Comment: Close inspection, using either the edge of the glass (making a prism in essence), or using a light source that is small relative to the glass thickness will show chromatic aberration.

Comment: @draculin, can you explain in a bit more detail what exactly you are telling in answer format, as this question want answer not I comment sir ?please sir explain in detail if possible a rough diagram explaining what EXACTLY  is happening? Requesting

Comment: @ draculin, also please tell , that u said that when light come out  from galss slab after dispersion   than do they (adjacent)overlap and therefore appear white(read that linked answer please) or each ray disperse wavelength parallel and dispersed wavelength from  adjacent do NOT overlap, just because of their small distance between the. It appears white to us? Basically is that ACTUALLY white formed after dispersion due to overlapping or just appear to us as brain cannt detect such minute distance between them  ? Than what happen in prism , distance between dispersed wavelength is also very

Comment: Small to notice by eyes( comparatively larger than slab stoll smaller for brain to notice)still we can see spectrum . Please **must include these doubts in your answer please sir** requesting